# Change text colors by clicking on button with javascript

Tags: javascript, colors

i want to change color of text by clicking button with javascript. I have problem with my code. It's changing color, but counter variable is not resetting to value of zero.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgLJG.png)stack.imgur.com/sFwbb.png

Comment: It should be counter = 0 while resetting and NOT counter === 0, counter === 0 is a condition and NOT assignment.

Comment: Also the the rest of the code should not be wrapped inside `else`, unless you want to skip that button click that resets `counter` to 0

Comment: Do not use an image to show your code. Place the example code inside the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 8 your are doing a comparison check using triple equals "===" instead of an assignment using the "=". In order to set the value of a variable use the assignment operator "=". Your new code will be this on line 8:

```
counter = 0;
```